# How to write a delegate that delegates to another property?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to reduce duplicated code in my custom property getters / setters that only proxy to identical properties in a different layer. The code explains it better:

```
var emailText
    get() = presenter.emailText
    set(value) {
        presenter.emailText = value
    }
```

What I'm aiming for is something like this:

```
var emailText by PropertyDelegate(presenter.emailText)
```

The problem is that I can't find the proper syntax to reference the actual property instead of its value. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a delegate according to the description in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html):

```
class PropertyDelegate<R>(private val prop: KProperty<R>) {
    private fun ensureDifference(prop1: KProperty<*>, prop2: KProperty<*>) {
        if (prop1.javaField == prop2.javaField) throw IllegalArgumentException("Can't delegate to same property.")
    }

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): R {
        ensureDifference(prop, property)
        return prop.getter.call()
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: R) {
        ensureDifference(prop, property)
        return (prop as? KMutableProperty<R>)?.setter?.call(value)
                ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Cannot set val property")
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
class X(var xProp: String)

class Y(var x: X) {
    var y: String by PropertyDelegate(x::xProp)
}
```

Note that this one should only be used with mutable `var` properties.

Comment: Great answer thanks! I'm a bit disappointed that I can't avoid reflection but it makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 1):

To get the property you can do `presenter::emailText`. It returns a [`KProperty`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property/)

Comment: Thanks, this helps! But now I'm stuck with the actual Delegate implementation.

is there a way to call the getters / setters from that KProperty without casting and reflection?

Comment: class PropertyDelegate<T>(private var property: KProperty<T>) : ReadWriteProperty<Any, T> {
    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>) : T = property.getter.call() as T

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        ...
    }
}

Comment: @pandulapeter write this.property.getter.call() and this.property.getter.set(value)